# why Installed module in python throws error

Tags: python, cntk

I installed cntk module in my system but whenever I try to run a code it says no module found

```
import cntk as C
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cntk'
```

Comment: you mean in your python environment

Comment: Is this linux/windows ?

Comment: in windows @Simplecode

Comment: You are probably using the wrong python interpreter ( I assume you have more than one python installed on your machine)

Comment: @vuun0 yes created env using conda and installed in that env

Comment: @JacobGokul run this command conda list to check if cntk is installed in your environment.

Comment: @vuun0  i ran that already it installed and checked but not importing

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `deep-learning` or `artificial-intelligence` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple problem. You do not have cntk installed*. The answer is same in any "No module named X" questions.

### 1) Check your python interpreter

inside the same script that throws the error, run

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

It prints, for example `C:\Python\Python 3.8.6\python.exe`. Let's call this `<path_to_python>`.

### 2) Install the package with the correct interpreter

Instead of

```
pip install cntk
```

run, (in case or regular Python installation)

```
"<path_to_python>" -m pip install cntk
```

or, if the `<path_to_python>` points to conda python, you need to activate that conda environment and

```
conda install cntk
```

or install with

```
conda install -n <name_of_env> cntk
```

---

* You might have it installed to *different* python folder/virtual environment.